# this within a arrow notation function within an object literall

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this

Lets say I have this Object:

```
    api = {
        x: 2,
        func: () => {
            this.x
        }
    }
```

If I call api.function, how come `this` is scoped to the `window` and not `api`?

If I turn func into a regular anonymous function `this` is scoped to the `api` and not the `window`.

Can anyone explain this to me? I thought the arrow notation inherited the parent this, which is `api`

Comment: `this` is not "scoped to `api`" with a regular `function`, it's dynamically passed depending on how the function is called.

Comment: so let me see if I understand. For the regular function, during runtime `api.func`, `this` is scoped to the `api` because `api` is calling it. For the arrow notation, since the arrow notation gets the scope from its parent, during run time, this is the `window`. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, it doesn't matter how you call the arrow function, it always gets the `this` value from where the function was defined (which should be `undefined` in your case, assuming strict mode).

Answer (score 2):

Arrow functions inherit `this` from their lexical scope, meaning the same value that `this` would mean in the scope they're defined in.

That's whatever `this` is in the function that contains that code; it has nothing to do with where in that scope you put the arrow function.

Comment: *"it has nothing to do with where you put the arrow function"* - Um...I know what you meant, but the lexical scope is determined by where you put it, so...

Comment: @nnnnnn: Good point; clarified.

Comment: More generally, "*…`this` in the function that contains that code*" could be "*…`this` in the execution context that contains that code*", since the OP is global code, not function code.

Answer (score 0):

Simple explanation: problem is that the function is created before the `api` object and it is specifically bound to the window in your case because you are in a `window` scope. If I slightly rewrite your code using ES5 `bind` you can get the following

```
const func = function() {
  this.x
}.bind(this); // here this is a window in your case

api = {
    x: 2,
    func: func 
}
```

This code is equivalent to yours. Here you can clearly see that your function does not belong to the object `api`.

Comment: *"This code is fully identical to yours"* - No it's not. Perhaps you meant to say that it is *equivalent*? (Except it isn't, quite: the OP's arrow function returns `undefined`.)

Comment: Updated the answer. Still I think the main thing is the explanation, not the wording and returned result that does not play here any role